# setuptools/easy_install does not install *.cfg files and locale directories?

Tags: python, distribution, setuptools, easy-install

I have a little problem with setuptools/easy_install; maybe someone could give me a hint what might be the cause of the problem:

To easily distribute one of my python webapps to servers I use setuptools' `sdist` command to build a tar.gz file which is copied to servers and locally installed using `easy_install /path/to/file.tar.gz`.

So far this seems to work great. I have listed everything in the `MANIFEST.in` file like this:

```
global-include */*.py */*.mo */*.po */*.pot */*.css */*.js */*.png */*.jpg */*.ico */*.woff */*.gif */*.mako */*.cfg
```

And the resulting tar.gz file does indeed contain all of the files I need.

It gets weird as soon as easy_install tries to actually install it on the remote system. For some reason a directory called `locales` and a configuration file called `migrate.cfg` won't get installed. This is odd and I can't find any documentaiton about this, but I guess it's some automatic ignore feature of easy_install?

Is there something like that? And if so, how do I get easy_install to install the `locales` and `migrate.cfg` files?

Thanks!

For reference here is the content of my `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


requires = ['flup', 'pyramid', 'WebError', 'wtforms', 'webhelpers', 'pil', 'apns', \
            'pyramid_beaker', 'sqlalchemy', 'poster', 'boto', 'pypdf', 'sqlalchemy_migrate', \
            'Babel']

version_number = execfile('pubserverng/version.py')

setup(
    author='Bastian',
    author_email='test@domain.com',
    url='http://domain.de/',
    name = "mywebapp",
    install_requires = requires,
    version = __version__,
    packages = find_packages(),
    zip_safe=False,
    entry_points = {
        'paste.app_factory': [
            'pubserverng=pubserverng:main'
        ]
    },

    namespace_packages = ['pubserverng'],

    message_extractors = { 'pubserverng': [
            ('**.py', 'python', None),
            ('templates/**.html', 'mako', None),
            ('templates/**.mako', 'mako', None),
            ('static/**', 'ignore', None),
            ('migrations/**', 'ignore', None), 
        ]
    },


)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question this quickly, but after some trial and error I found out what the reason behind the missing files was. In fact it was more than one reason:

- The `SOURCES.txt` file was older and included a full list of *most* files, which resulted in them being bundled correctly.
- The `MANIFEST.in` file was correct, too, so all required files were actually in the .tar.gz archive as expected. The main problem was that a few files simply would not get installed on the target machine.
- I had to add `include_package_data = True,` to my setup.py file. After doing that all files installed as expected.

I'll have to put some research into `include_package_data` to find out if this weird behavior is documented somewhere. setuptools is a real mess - especially the documentation.

Comment: This might be what you want, but it might not.. :-)  All `include_package_data = True` means is that setuptools should install files in package directories that are not known by python to be related to the package.  Setting this option means now you have to be super careful to make sure that MANIFEST.in excludes files you don't want included (and gets updated when people add files).

Answer (score 2):

The entire package distribution system in python leaves a lot to be desired. My issues were similar to yours and were eventually solved by using `distutils` (rather than `setuptools`) which honored the `include_package_data = True` setting as expected.

Using `distutils` allowed me to more or less keep required file list in `MANIFEST.in`and avoid using the `package_data` setting where I would have had to duplicate the source list; the draw back is `find_packages` is not available. Below is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
package = __import__('simplemenu')

setup(name='django-simplemenu',
    version=package.get_version(),
    url='http://github.com/danielsokolowski/django-simplemenu',
    license='BSD',
    description=package.__doc__.strip(),
    author='Alex Vasi <eee@someuser.com>, Justin Steward <justin+github@justinsteward.com>, Daniel Sokolowski <unemelpmis-ognajd@danols.com>',
    author_email='unemelpmis-ognajd@danols.com',
    include_package_data=True, # this will read MANIFEST.in during install phase
    packages=[
        'simplemenu',
        'simplemenu.migrations',
        'simplemenu.templatetags',
    ],
    # below is no longer needed as we are utilizing MANIFEST.in with include_package_data setting
    #package_data={'simplemenu': ['locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/*', 
    #                             'locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/*']
    #              },
    scripts=[],
    requires=[],
    )
```

And here is a `MANIFEST.in` file:

```
    include LICENSE
    include README.rst
    recursive-include simplemenu *.py
    recursive-include simplemenu/locale *
    prune simplemenu/migrations
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`data_files`](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) functionality of `setup` - your files aren't code, so `easy_install` won't install them by default (it doesn't know where they go).

The upside of this is that these files are added to MANIFEST automatically - you don't need to do any magic to get them there yourself.  (In general if a MANIFEST automatically generated by `setup.py` isn't sufficient, adding them yourself isn't going to magically get them installed.)

Comment: That's why I use the MANIFEST.in file, and it works for most data files, like PNGs and .mako templates. So this is weird.

Comment: See my own answer. Seems like include_package_data was missing.

Comment: @badcat: See my comment - I would argue that in general `include_package_data` is not a feature you want to use - I find packaging to be much more sane when you are forced to explicitly include data files you want to ship, rather than exclude data files you don't want to ship.

Comment: That's exactly my the point. Since I use git, the automatic packaging does not work anyway. But what is really weird is the fact that `include_package_data` must be `True` so that even manually defined patterns from `MANIFEST.in` will be installed on the target machine.

Comment: @badcat: MANIFEST.in just specifies what ends up in the source distribution when you run `sdist` - it doesn't have anything to do with what gets installed.  `setup` still needs to be told where to install these files.

Comment: Ah, that isn't quite clear. I thought everything that ended up in the .tar.gz file would be installed later on. The whole documentation is a real mess, though; really hard to get a grip on such details